# Best way to add mobile version to a Rails WebSite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo

I have a quick question about "mobile". I must add the mobile version to my website and I'm exploring all the solutions. Here are my choices:

1) Add media queries to css and trasform my fixed layout in a responsive layout.

Good: one layout only, code for Google bot is the same
Not good: code is heavier, on mobile I load all the js and CSS, impossibile to go to the desktop version

2) Rails 4.1 Variants

Good: i can create a lightweight mobile website, I can have desktop version, I can optimize the mobile experience, using the layout I can also create mobile apps with Cordova

Not Good: the HTML for the same page is different for desktop and mobile. I'm worried about SEO

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

There is no single best way. The answer depends on your specific needs and case. This is mostly an opinion-based question.

Both solutions are correct. However, the main difference is that the case (1) is more limited compared to case (2). The CSS-based layout makes sense when you just want to make sure the main version works well on mobile devices. It's not a real optimization, because the device will have to load the entire page in any case.

The second option (2) is a real optimization. By providing device-optimized templates, you can skip the pieces that the mobile device doesn't need (such as big images, unnecessary item listing, etc) effectively reducing the weight of the page. You can also inject mobile-specific features.

The SEO issue is a non-issue. You can instruct the search engines to ignore the SEO content using the appropriate meta tags or you can also use the [`canonical` tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) if you should decide to provide the content under a different path or domain (for instance if you add a specific extension for the mobile-optimized pages).

Comment: Yep, there is no single best way. However, Google recommends responsive design these days. With responsive, you don't have to worry about redirects, separate sitemaps for mobile and desktop, etc. etc. It really eliminates a whole lot of issues in a go. 
If you need a mobile SEO guide, here is a good one (and it's recent) http://www.link-assistant.com/news/mobile-seo.html